# Oracle APEX Fixing Date Format for Calendar Invitation

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am using the date format DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI (Greek format date-time)
I have 'F_ICAL_EVENTS' function :

```
create or replace FUNCTION F_ICAL_EVENTS (
   p_summary       IN   VARCHAR2,
   p_description   IN   VARCHAR2,
   p_start_date    IN   DATE,
   p_end_date      IN   DATE
)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   lv_desc      VARCHAR2 (1000);
   lv_summary   VARCHAR2 (500);
   lv_dtstart   VARCHAR2 (100);
   lv_date      VARCHAR2 (100);
   lv_dtend     VARCHAR2 (100);
   l_retval     VARCHAR2 (2000);
   l_lf         CHAR (1)         := CHR (10);
BEGIN
   lv_summary := 'SUMMARY:' || p_summary;
   lv_date :=
         'DTSTAMP:'
      || TO_DATE (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
      || 'T'
      || TO_CHAR (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'HH24:MI:SS');
   lv_dtstart :=
         'DTSTART:'
      || TO_DATE (p_start_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
      || 'T'
      || TO_CHAR (p_start_date, 'HH24:MI');
   lv_dtend :=
         'DTEND:'
      || TO_DATE (p_end_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
      || 'T'
      || TO_CHAR (p_end_date, 'HH24:MI');
   l_retval :=
         'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-// Oracle Application Express //ENCAL
SCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
'
      || lv_date
      || CHR (10)
      || lv_dtstart
      || CHR (10)
      || lv_dtend
      || CHR (10)
      || lv_summary
      || CHR (10)
      || lv_desc
      || '
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_retval);
   RETURN l_retval;
END F_ICAL_EVENTS;
```

that takes a date time value from my page dynamic action like this:

```
SELECT F_ICAL_EVENTS (p_summary          => v_summary,
                                p_description      => v_descr,
                                p_start_date       => to_date(:P2003_SESSION_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'),
                                p_end_date         => to_date(:P2003_SESSION_STOP, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
                                )
            INTO l_ical_event
            FROM DUAL;
```

The problem is when I receive the invitation, the date and time is wrong. For example my Start_date is 10/08/2021 16:00 (10th August) and i gets 8 Dec 0009 12:00. 
The session.ics attachment i think is correct:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-// Oracle Application Express //GR
SCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:16-08-2021T12:11:37
DTSTART:10-08-2021T16:00
DTEND:10-08-2021T17:00
SUMMARY:New Appointment! 
                               
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

This is the notification I receive in my Gmail:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Apex pages, all items are *strings*. Date picker uses format you set for that item, but it is still a string.

If you set the format to `DD-MM-YYYY H24:MI`, then calling the procedure looks OK because format masks match.

```
p_start_date       => to_date(:P2003_SESSION_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
```

However, if procedure's parameters datatypes are `DATE`, then this is wrong:

```
|| TO_DATE (p_start_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

That should be `TO_CHAR` instead, just as you used it for

```
|| TO_CHAR (p_start_date, 'HH24:MI');
```

---

**[EDIT]**

Apparently, it was about format mask. For completeness, posting it here from a comment:

According to this page ([How to Insert Google Calendar Invites in Your Marketing Emails](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/google-calendar-invites-in-email-marketing)), date/time format mask should be `YYYYMMDDTHHMISS`.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot and thank you for your answer. I change it to TO_CHAR, still nothing....

Comment: Did you change it for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as well? That's wrong too (didn't notice earlier): `|| TO_DATE (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MM-YYYY')`

Comment: Yes Initially I had them as TO_CHAR, then I changed them so that they might work as TO_DATE. Now Everything is TO_CHAR again, but still gets wrong dates in my gmail but the session.ics attachment is correct

Comment: According to this page (https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/google-calendar-invites-in-email-marketing), date/time format mask should be `YYYYMMDDTHHMISS`. Did you try it?

Comment: I change it to YYYYMMDDTHHMISS and it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`. You appear to want `TO_CHAR` instead:

```sql
create or replace FUNCTION F_ICAL_EVENTS (
   p_summary       IN   VARCHAR2,
   p_description   IN   VARCHAR2,
   p_start_date    IN   DATE,
   p_end_date      IN   DATE
)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   l_retval     VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
   l_retval   := 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-// Oracle Application Express //ENCAL
SCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:' || TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MM-YYYY"T"HH24:MI:SS') || '
DTSTART:' || TO_CHAR(p_start_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY"T"HH24:MI') || '
DTEND:' || TO_CHAR(p_end_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY"T"HH24:MI') || '
SUMMARY:' || p_summary || '
' || p_description || '
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_retval);
   RETURN l_retval;
END F_ICAL_EVENTS;
/
```

Also, if `:P2003_SESSION_DATE` and `:P2003_SESSION_STOP` are `DATE` bind variables then you do not need `TO_DATE` and can just use:

```sql
SELECT F_ICAL_EVENTS (
         p_summary     => v_summary,
         p_description => v_descr,
         p_start_date  => :P2003_SESSION_DATE,
         p_end_date    => :P2003_SESSION_STOP,
       )
INTO   l_ical_event
FROM   DUAL;
```

If the bind variables are strings then you will need `TO_DATE` and keep your calling query as you had it but could simplify it to remove the `SELECT` statement and just use a PL/SQL assignment:

```sql
l_ical_event := F_ICAL_EVENTS (
                  p_summary     => v_summary,
                  p_description => v_descr,
                  p_start_date  => TO_DATE(:P2003_SESSION_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'),
                  p_end_date    => TO_DATE(:P2003_SESSION_STOP, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
                );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=18f38f7112e2bf240f02fe8442b46646)*

---

If the external service you are using is expecting dates in ISO8601 format then use `YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS`.

```sql
create or replace FUNCTION F_ICAL_EVENTS (
   p_summary       IN   VARCHAR2,
   p_description   IN   VARCHAR2,
   p_start_date    IN   DATE,
   p_end_date      IN   DATE
)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   l_retval     VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
   l_retval   := 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-// Oracle Application Express //ENCAL
SCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:' || TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') || '
DTSTART:' || TO_CHAR(p_start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') || '
DTEND:' || TO_CHAR(p_end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') || '
SUMMARY:' || p_summary || '
' || p_description || '
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_retval);
   RETURN l_retval;
END F_ICAL_EVENTS;
/
```

Comment: Hi @MT0and thank you for your answer. I change the function, but still nothing

Comment: @Dorito [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=18f38f7112e2bf240f02fe8442b46646) works fine for me.